# Cannot install react-leaflet-choropleth with npm

Tags: react-leaflet

Good day,

I am trying to install react-leaflet choropleth and have run the following in my React app's directory:

```
npm install react-leaflet-choropleth
```

This has resulted in the following errors:
[Errors screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQzJF.png)

(I needed to hide some info on the screenshot for confidentiality reasons)

**How do I resolve these errors?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look into [react-leaflet-chloropleth's package.json](https://github.com/LiveBy/react-leaflet-choropleth/blob/master/package.json), you'll see that it has a peerDependency of react-leaflet version ^1 or ^2.  You're trying to use it with react-leaflet version 3.

Newer versions of node and npm are considering legacy peer dependencies as errors (they used to be warnings), and in this case, I agree.  react-leaflet-chloropleth will most certainly not work with react-leaflet version 3, and npm is letting you know that.  (Not all errors of this type mean certain doom, but in this case, it does.)

React-leaflet v3 had a lot of breaking changes since react-leaflet-choropleth was written.  You'll either need to downgrade to a version of react-leaflet that is compatible with this plugin (not recommended!), or rewrite it for react-leaflet v3.  (Its not as hard as it sounds, and there are many other questions on here discussing how to port leaflet plugins into react-leaflet v3.  start with [vanilla leaflet-chloropleth](https://github.com/timwis/leaflet-choropleth)).

Comment: thanks for your reply. I'll see what I can do. Is there another way to make choropleth maps using react-leaflet without using react-leaflet-choropleth?

Comment: There certainly is, but that deserves its own question.  I made mention of that in my third paragraph.  However, many questions have been asked about creating custom components for react-leaflet v3 using leaflet plugins, so I'd start by searching around